# How could be the SDL drawing function optimized? - instead of calculating all points

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I have written a program in C with SDL2 to draw 3D-function. My problem is that it works almost fine with not too complex functions, but with complicated functions it just takes too much time to calculate all the points.
First it calculates all the points in 3D:

```
void calculate_points(float points[RANGE*RANGE][3]){
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int x = - RANGE/2; x < RANGE/2; x++){
        for(int y = -RANGE/2; y < RANGE/2; y++){
            points[cnt][0] = x; 
            points[cnt][1] = y;
            points[cnt][2] = x+y*y;
            cnt ++;
        }
    }
}
```

then it rotates these points and draws them:

```
void rotate_points(const float points[RANGE*RANGE][3], float rotated[RANGE*RANGE][3], int size, float angle){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        rotated[i][0] = points[i][0];
        rotated[i][1] = (cos(angle) * points[i][1] - sin(angle) * points[i][2]);
        rotated[i][2] = (cos(angle) * points[i][2] + sin(angle) * points[i][1]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        rotated[i][1] = rotated[i][1];
        rotated[i][0] = (cos(angle) * rotated[i][0] + sin(angle) * rotated[i][2]);
        rotated[i][2] = (cos(angle) * rotated[i][2] - sin(angle) * rotated[i][0]);
    }
 }

void draw_function(SDL_Renderer * renderer, SDL_FPoint *p, int size, int *colors) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 235, colors[i], 42, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawPointF(renderer, p[i].x, p[i].y);
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
 }
```

I was thinking if I could maybe first render the whole function as an image or something like that and rotate that but I have no clue on which path should I begin to optimize it. I am thinking the animation is blinking too because it has to calculate all the points every time.

The whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SC_WIDTH 500
#define SC_HEIGHT 500
#define RANGE 200

// functions for the graph
void calculate_points(float points[RANGE*RANGE][3]){
    int cnt = 0;
    for(int x = - RANGE/2; x < RANGE/2; x++){
        for(int y = -RANGE/2; y < RANGE/2; y++){
            points[cnt][0] = x; 
            points[cnt][1] = y;
            points[cnt][2] = x+y*y;
            cnt ++;
        }
    }
}

float search_max(const float points[RANGE*RANGE][3]){
    int max = points[0][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < RANGE*RANGE; i++){
        if(points[i][2] > max){
            max = points[i][2];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

float search_min(const float points[RANGE*RANGE][3]){
    int min = points[0][2];
    for(int i = 0; i < RANGE*RANGE; i++){
        if(points[i][2] < min){
            min = points[i][2];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

// OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin)  
// NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin)  
// NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin
void scale_function(float points[RANGE*RANGE][3]){
    float old_min = search_min(points);
    float old_max = search_max(points);
    float old_range = old_max - old_min;
    float new_range = RANGE;
    for (int i = 0; i < RANGE*RANGE; i++){
        points[i][2] = (((points[i][2] - old_min) * new_range) / old_range) - RANGE/2;
    }
}

void rotate_points(const float points[RANGE*RANGE][3], float rotated[RANGE*RANGE][3], int size, float angle){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        rotated[i][0] = points[i][0];
        rotated[i][1] = (cos(angle) * points[i][1] - sin(angle) * points[i][2]);
        rotated[i][2] = (cos(angle) * points[i][2] + sin(angle) * points[i][1]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        rotated[i][1] = rotated[i][1];
        rotated[i][0] = (cos(angle) * rotated[i][0] + sin(angle) * rotated[i][2]);
        rotated[i][2] = (cos(angle) * rotated[i][2] - sin(angle) * rotated[i][0]);
    }
}

void project_points(SDL_FPoint *output, float src[RANGE*RANGE][3], int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        output[i].x = SC_WIDTH/2 + src[i][0];
        output[i].y = SC_HEIGHT/2 - src[i][1];
    }
}

void color_function(int *color, const float points[RANGE*RANGE][3]){
    float old_min = search_min(points);
    float old_max = search_max(points);
    float old_range = old_max - old_min;
    float new_range = 255;
    for (int i = 0; i < RANGE*RANGE; i++){
        color[i] = (int)(((points[i][2] - old_min) * 255) / old_range);
    }
}

void draw_function(SDL_Renderer * renderer, SDL_FPoint *p, int size, int *colors) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 235, colors[i], 42, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawPointF(renderer, p[i].x, p[i].y);
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void clear(SDL_Renderer * renderer) {
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // function
    float function_points[RANGE*RANGE][3];
    float rotated_function[RANGE*RANGE][3] = {0.0};
    SDL_FPoint function_p[RANGE*RANGE] = {0.0};
    float function_angle = 0.0;
    int colors[RANGE*RANGE] = {0};
    calculate_points(function_points);
    scale_function(function_points);
    color_function(colors, function_points);

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0){
            printf("error initializing SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            return 1;
    }

    SDL_Window* win = SDL_CreateWindow("Plot",
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                        SC_WIDTH, SC_HEIGHT, 0);
    if (!win){
        printf("error creating window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
       
    Uint32 render_flags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED;
    SDL_Renderer* rend = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, render_flags);
    if (!rend){
        printf("error creating renderer: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }
    int close_requested = 0;
    while(!close_requested){
        SDL_Event event;
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case SDL_QUIT:
                    close_requested = 1;
                    break;
            }
        }

        function_angle = function_angle + 0.01;
        rotate_points(function_points, rotated_function, RANGE*RANGE, function_angle);
        project_points(function_p, rotated_function, RANGE*RANGE);
        clear(rend);
        draw_function(rend, function_p, RANGE*RANGE, colors);
        SDL_Delay(30);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Start using OpenGL. Those computations will be a lot faster on a GPU.

Comment: The reason why it's blinking is because you're only supposed to call `SDL_RenderPresent` once per frame, after drawing everything.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think it is called only once per frame, it's inside the draw function and it is only called once. Edit: sorry you are right it was called in the clear function too. Thanks!